# gRPC Stackdriver issue

Tags: grpc, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, opencensus

I have tried to log call stack info through opencensus. I have enabled permission in google account. I am using default credentials method. Stackdriver Trace API is enabled for the corresponding account.
 Permission for `monitoring.viewer`, `monitoring.editor` and `cloudtrace` are also given.
Still, we are facing below-mentioned error from client side while pushing the logs.

```
2019/02/21 12:40:14 Failed to export to Stackdriver: rpc error: code = NotFound desc = Requested entity was not found.

2019/02/21 12:37:47 Failed to export to Stackdriver: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Permission monitoring.metricDescriptors.create denied (or the resource may not exist).
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the project the application running on and one for the monitoring running are same? Also, can you confirm to what you have given the permission?

Comment: Thanks mate. I did so many iterations of enbaling GRPC monitoring finally ending up at OpenCensus. I mistyped the project ID during this process. Thanks for pointing out such silly mistakes. I was so frustrated that I was about to start openTracing with Prometheus setup.  :)

Comment: It's great to hear that your app worked as expected!